# Vue-i18n do not have default export

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-i18n

all! This is the first time I apply `vue-i18n` in my `typeScript + Vue` project. As the official site guided, I install it by using `yarn install vue-i18n`, then I want import it in `main.ts` via `import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'`, and it shows error below. Why this would happen and how could I fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
Module 
'"/Users/scott/Desktop/Pando/uikit-main/node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n"' 
has no default export. 
Did you mean to use 'import { VueI18n } from "/Users/scott/Desktop/Pando/uikit-main/node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n"' instead?ts(2613)
```

My `vue-i18n` version is `"vue-i18n": "^9.1.9"`. If I import `vue-i18n` as suggested, then if I continue to type `Vue.use(VueI18n)`, it will generate another error.

`'VueI18n' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`

I think this is because `vue-i18n` only export some interface.

```
(alias) interface VueI18n<Messages = {}, DateTimeFormats = {}, NumberFormats = {}>
import VueI18n
```

And backtrack the key word `VueI18n` in the import, I found it doesn't have any default export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to copy the route just like this (I use Vscode) and then paste it in the import part to guarantee there are no mistakes in the route?

[image]

Also you can try with this import **import { VueI18n } from "/Users/scott/Desktop/Pando/uikit-main/node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n"** instead **VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'**

Comment: Also you can try with this import { VueI18n } from "/Users/scott/Desktop/Pando/uikit-main/node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n" instead VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Comment: Tried. But it will generate another error when I use `Vue.use(VueI18n)`. This is probably because `vue-i18n` I installed just export some interfaces.

Comment: I use "vue-i18n": "^8.24.2" and it works fine with the import you're doing.
My route is /node_modules/vue-i18n/types/index

Comment: Thx! It worked for me! I just changed the version of `vue-i18n` and reinstall it.

Comment: @张俊旭 For your information, vue-i18n `9.x` is meant for Vue.js 3. https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/installation.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to import like `import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'`

Do not import as `import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";` Because, it has not export default.